# Extjs 6.5+ Adding Components to Container Gives Empty Viewport

Tags: extjs, extjs6

Not sure why I'm getting an empty viewport. I am defining subclasses as components and trying to get the viewport to display the 2 components created. Seems simple enough yet coming up empty?

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyHeader', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    items: [{

        xtype: 'titlebar',
        title: '<a href="#">Logo</a>',
        titleAlign: 'left',
        cls: 'im-titlebar',
        dock: 'top',
        id: 'titlebar',
        items: [

            {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Log In',
                align: 'right',
                ui: 'action',
                margin: '',
                ariaRole: 'button',
                cls: 'btn-im-login action noprint',
                id: 'button_LogIn'
            }
        ]

    }]
});

Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyFooter', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',

    items: [{
        xtype: 'container',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Button',
            align: 'right',
            ui: 'action',
            ariaRole: 'button',
            cls: 'btn-im-login action noprint',
            id: 'button_Button'
        }]

    }]

});

Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyView', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    requires: ['MyApp.view.MyHeader', 'MyApp.view.MyFooter']
});

Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled: false
});

Ext.application({
    name: 'MyApp',
    launch: function () {
        Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('MyApp.view.MyView'));
    }
});
```

[See fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/35qm)

Comment: I was able to solve the issue by adding items and declaring xtype to those items from the alias of each component- added to fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does what you have defined.

You need to add the Header and Footer components as items.

---

I would suggest that you may try to to use a panel and / or use tbar, bbar or header configs available there.

docs:

https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.panel.Panel.html
https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.panel.Panel.html#cfg-dockedItems
https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.panel.Panel.html#cfg-header
https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.panel.Panel.html#cfg-bbar

---

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'MyApp',
    launch: function () {
        var f = Ext.create('MyApp.view.MyHeader', {
            flex: 1
        });
        var h = Ext.create('MyApp.view.MyFooter', {
            flex: 1
        });
        Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('MyApp.view.MyView', {
            layout: {
                type: 'vbox',
                align: 'stretch'
            },
            items: [h, f]
        }));
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes it's easy enough to add html and get something, but how do I add the header and footer as items? I tried items: ['MyApp.view.MyHeader', 'MyApp.view.MyFooter'] but that produced invalid config error. I want to keep the header and footer as their own classes in this case.

Comment: Sure, but thats not the question you have asked for. The fiddle does not have any items.
You need to either create them first or you need to add them as config using an xtype.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to require views, but you should add it to parent view by  `items` array.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyHeader', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    xtype: 'myheader',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'titlebar',
        title: '<a href="#">Logo</a>'
    }]
});

Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyFooter', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    xtype: 'myfooter',

    items: [{
        xtype: 'container',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Button'
        }]
    }]
});

Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyView', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    xtype: 'myView',
    height: 100,
    items: [{
        xtype: 'myheader'
    }, {
        xtype: 'myfooter'
    }]
});

Ext.application({
    name: 'MyApp',
    launch: function () {
        Ext.Viewport.add({
            xtype: 'myView'
        });
    }
});
```

Remember - classic toolkit does not have `Ext.Viewport` class.

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'MyApp',

    launch : function() {
        Ext.create({
            xtype: 'panel',
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            bodyPadding: 20,
            tbar: {
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'label',
                    text: 'Header'
                }]
            },
            bbar: {
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'label',
                    text: 'footer'
                }]
            },
            items: [{
                xtype: 'form',
                title: 'My Form',
                layout: 'form',
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'someField'
                }]
            }]
        });

    }
});
```

Comment: In the classic framework, Ext.Viewport exists as alternateClassName for Ext.container.Viewport. https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.2/classic/src/Viewport.js.html